# Disable editing part of input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know I can disable/lock part of an input box using

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled"/>
```

or

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly"/>
```

but I want to have

```
<input type="text" value="[[inputbox|edithere]]"/>
```

where the user can only edit `edithere`

I have tried to google this, however the only related things I can find are how to disable an input box completely or disable certain keys.

I don't know the input boxes `id` or how many there are (dynamically created via php onload), but I know that they will always be  a pipeline and two ]] bookending the value I want to edit.

**EDIT**

**http://jsfiddle.net/7rTMK/**

Comment: Are you trying to set a static value to the text box that the user can then append their input onto?

Comment: You want a text input to work like a text input?

Comment: Use a label with the data that will prepended onto the user's data so they can see that data and add their own to the text box.

Comment: How about `[[inputbox| <input type="text" placeholder="edithere" />]]`?

Comment: @ChadCook I have edited my post with a fiddle link - the user can type in the second section of the box (after pipeline) and the result is displayed in in a div. I want the entire value in the input box but want to explore the possibility of locking everything before the pipeline and after the two square brackets. Thanks.

Comment: You can't, there's no way to to this. Graphically, you might be able to make something which *looks* like a half-editable text box, but you shouldn't. Just put the fixed portion of the string *infront* of the textbox, or give them a live preview of what their text will look like.

Comment: Ya.  You can't straight up do this.  You can only make something that looks like it works like this.  Twitter bootstrap has some pretty good examples for you to look at for styled prepended labels/text

Comment: You can always fake it -> http://jsfiddle.net/ZwbWq/1/

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this with a stock input just manipulating attributes.

However you can  simulate this with css and some extra markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="static text">static text</div>
    <input class="text" type="text" />
</div>
```

Position "static text" div on top of the input and add left padding to the input text.

example http://jsfiddle.net/MTEec/

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible. Use a tag to wrap the input, and put the uneditable parts before, or after the input, and style the tag to look like an input, and style the input to match that styling.

If you need the form to send all the data, create a hidden input after your input, and update it's value with JavaScript (to the static and the input's text concatenated) upon changing the value of the main input. That way when the form is sent, the later hidden input with the same name will be used.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not entirely impossible to do, it would be extremely difficult to do and it's a very bad practice to try doing something like that, at least for your use case.

You should obtain the user input without restriction inside your input box, if you want to add square brackets or the such, you can add them **later** using either Javascript or your service side language.

Alternatively, if you really wish to display the characters inside the textbox, you can use claustrofob's solution and mess around with the CSS.